# Head.js `.js()` method

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, head.js

I have some code I inherited from my job, and it uses an api call from [head.js](http://headjs.com):

```
head.js( { 'application' : 'someurl.com/foo.js' });
```

Does this register the javascript asset as `application`, so when I call

```
head.load( 'application' );
```

the right behavior will happen? I couldn't find this method in the head.js api page, nor in a google search.

Comment: Does that `head.js` call actually _work?_

Comment: @MattBall yes, `head.js` in the console returns `function lt()` :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`head.js( { 'application' : 'someurl.com/foo.js' });` - means that you add label to loading some foo.js file then you can use `ready` function to callback a function that do some stuff. For example:

```
// Labels are usually used in conjuntion with: head.ready()
head.ready("application", function() {
   // do something
});
```

`head.load( 'application' );` - will tries to load application file for root folder.